# Изменение / удаление строки из модели QSqlRelationTableModel не отображается в БД SQLite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtableview

Я использую QTableView в связке с QSortFilterProxyModel, QSqlRelationalTableModel и делегат FlipProxyDelegate (родитель QSqlRelationalDelegate). Изменение или удаление строки в QTableView не отражается в базе данных.

Пробовал использовать QTableView c QSqlRelationalTableModel и QSqlRelationalDelegate результата не дало

Фрагмент кода создания модели:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel * tableModel = new QSqlRelationalTableModel;
tableModel->setTable( currentTable );
tableModel->setEditStrategy( QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit );

createRelations( tableModel, currentTable );

filterView->setItemDelegate( new FlipProxyDelegate(tableModel) );
tableModel->select();

sortModel->setSourceModel( tableModel );
filterView->setModel( sortModel );
```

Подтверждение транзакции:

```
void InterfaceChanger::submit()
{
    FilterTableView *filterView = (FilterTableView*)ui->layout->itemAt(0)->widget();
    QSortFilterProxyModel * sortModel = (QSortFilterProxyModel *)filterView->getModel();
    QSqlTableModel *model = (QSqlTableModel *)sortModel->sourceModel();
    model->database().transaction();
    if (model->submitAll())
    {
        model->database().commit();
        model->select();
    }
    else
    {
        model->database().rollback();
        QMessageBox::critical( nullptr,
                               "Ошибка",
                               model->lastError().databaseText());
    }

}
```

[Полный исходный код проекта](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/QY2PV829rlb3Vg)

Comment: Приложите ваш код без ссылки, это можно сделать в поле редактирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не установил primary key для таблиц, содержащих внешние ключи